# PayPal Sandbox - Where are the accept / reject links for pending transactions in the new interface

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to test echeck payments in the PayPal sandbox environment, but I cannot find where they've put the accept/reject links for each transaction in the new interface.

Here's what I've done:

1. Set the user account payment review to "On" (as described here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_payment-review/).
2. Submitted a payment using the account.
3. Logged into Sandbox.

The payment displays as pending on the Account Summary page and the Activity page (https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/myaccount/activity).  If I click the payment, the page expands to show the payment details, but there's no way to approve or reject the payment.

In the previous interface, you could drill down to the individual transaction and approve it or decline it to trigger the appropriate message back to your application.

However, I can't find these links in the current interface, and I haven't found mention of them in the PayPal documentation or here.  Can anyone point me to them?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Kindly contact PayPal Merchant Technical support team to assist on this.

https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask